# Why doesn't append() work with input tag?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to append `<i>Some Text</i>` after the value of the submit button. If I write it in HTML like in the code snippet, it works but if I use jQuery to append it works partially.

By partially I mean if you open Developer Tools, the appended text is present but it doesn't display on the browser screen.

[image]

Why does this happen?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.tryout').append('<i>Hello</i>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="tryout" type="submit"></input>

<hr>

<input type="submit"><i>Hello</i></input>
```

Comment: Is `<input>Value</input>` valid HTML? Isn't `<input>` a self-closing tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't append anything to an input element, use button instead

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tryout').append('<i>Hello</i>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="tryout" type="submit"></button>

<hr>

<button type="submit"><i>Hello</i></button>
```

---

Or if you want you can insert the new element as a sibling of the button using .after() like `$('.tryout').after('<i>Hello</i>');`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [.after](http://api.jquery.com/after/) instead of `.append()` to append element after certain element:

> Insert content, specified by the parameter, after each element in the set of matched elements.

```
 $('.tryout').after('<i>Hello</i>');
```